# Sidebar on Google Maps reacting to map

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers

I have a Google Map (API v3) populated with markers that indicate data from a database. I would like to add a sidebar that checks which markers are currently visible on the map and adds them to a sidebar, adjusting whenever map is moved. Is something like that possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have a [GitHub project](https://github.com/lightningwhelk/Geoxml3-Map) which loads a KML file containing placemarks, puts them in the sidebar, and uses the Google Maps API to dim / brighten the locations when changing the map.  The relevant portion is this snippet:

```
google.maps.event.addListener(mapInstance, 'bounds_changed', function() {
    currentBounds = mapInstance.getBounds();
    for (i = 0; i < parser.docs[0].placemarks.length; i++) {
        var myLi = $("#p" + i);
        if (currentBounds.contains(parser.docs[0].placemarks[i].marker.getPosition())) {
            myLi.css("color","#000000");
        } else {
            myLi.css("color","#CCCCCC");
        }
    }
});
```

The abbreviated version of that is:

```
google.maps.event.addListener(mapInstance, 'bounds_changed', function() {
    currentBounds = mapInstance.getBounds();
    /*
     Loop over Google map placemarks and check the placemark by doing:
     if (currentBounds.contains(currentPlacemark.getPosition())) {
       // Change CSS to make sidebar entry visible
     } else {
       // Change CSS to make sidebar entry invisible
     }
     */
});
```

In my examples, mapInstance is an instance of google.maps.Map, and currentPlacemark is an instance of one of your google.maps.Marker objects.